# Prop & store sync issue in grandchild component

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I have two variables, `a` and `b`, and three components nested in one another: `<Outer>` -> `<Middle>` -> `<Inner>`. `a` is fed as a prop into `<Outer>`, which creates a context. This context includes a store for `a` and thereby allows `<Inner>` to subscribe to `a`. `b` is fed directly into `<Inner>` as a prop.

My goal is to update (increment) `a` and `b` in the same code block and have `<Inner>` receive both updated values before updating the DOM. The desired result, which happens when I remove `<Middle>`, looks something like this:

```
a = 0; b = 0; sum = 0

a = 1; b = 1; sum = 2

a = 2; b = 2; sum = 4

a = 3; b = 3; sum = 6

a = 4; b = 4; sum = 8
```

but `$a` and `b` inside `<Inner>` are no longer in sync as soon as I put `<Middle>` back in:

```
a = 0; b = 0; sum = 0

a = 1; b = 0; sum = 1

a = 1; b = 1; sum = 2

a = 2; b = 1; sum = 3

a = 2; b = 2; sum = 4

a = 3; b = 2; sum = 5

a = 3; b = 3; sum = 6

a = 4; b = 3; sum = 7

a = 4; b = 4; sum = 8

a = 5; b = 4; sum = 9

a = 5; b = 5; sum = 10
```

Is there any way for me to keep `<Middle>` but still achieve the effect I want? I'm using Svelte 3.44.2 and Chromium 93.0.4577.58. REPL can be found here: https://svelte.dev/repl/879a436fe96d4445a5ba870cd37436f4?version=3.44.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Svelte by default **`'re-run reactive declarations whenever any of the referenced values change'`** so when the store updates the value of `a` it gets immediately updated in `outer component` and updates the refrence in `inner component` at this stage. then `middle before` fires first before firing the `inner component` then `b` gets updated which immediately updates the reference in `inner-component` again and the reactive statement of `$: calculations` re-evaluated again which reloads the loop.

this is your test without middle compenent

```
// on load

"outer before"
"inner calculations" ▶ Array(1)[ Object { … } ]
"inner before"
"inner after"
"outer after"

// on click

"outer before"
"inner calculations" ▶ Array(2)[ Object { … } , Object { … } ]
"inner before"
"outer after"
"inner after"
```

...

```
// on load

"outer before"
"middle before"
"inner calculations" ▶ Array(1)[ Object { … } ]
"inner before"
"inner after"
"middle after"
"outer after"

// on click

"outer before"
"inner calculations" ▶ Array(2)[ Object { … } , Object { … } ]
"inner before"
"middle before"
"inner calculations" ▶ Array(3)[ Object { … } , Object { … } , Object { … } ]
"inner before"
"outer after"
"inner after"
"middle after"
```

i see no solution to this problem other than binding both values to be updated at the same time of the component life-cycle or pass both using the store to do the same.

Comment: Hmm, I see. This is probably because [store values are updated in real time wheres prop values aren't](https://dev.to/isaachagoel/svelte-reactivity-gotchas-solutions-if-you-re-using-svelte-in-production-you-should-read-this-3oj3). 

Though I really hope there's a solution that keeps `<Middle>` there as well as `a` being passed via a store-in-context & `b` as a prop. In my actual use case, there are a lot of `<Inner>`'s, each with a different `b`, but they all use the same value for `a`.